# Как сделать отображение видео(opencv) в круглом QPixmap

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, opencv, qpixmap

Я пытаюсь сделать некий виджет, в котором будет отображаться видео с вебкамеры используя модуль cv2. У меня получилось это сделать, но только форме квадрата, а я хочу в форме круга.
[Вот тут](https://www.thetopsites.net/article/58713642.shtml) есть пример как сделать QPixmap скругленным, но мне не удалось применить к моему случаю.

Вот что у меня получается:
[image: Вот что у меня получается]

А вот как я хочу:
[image: А вот как я хочу]

Вот ui.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(231, 221)
        self.display_webcam_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.display_webcam_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 231, 221))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.display_webcam_label.setFont(font)
        self.display_webcam_label.setStyleSheet("background: #111;\n"
"color: #fff;\n"
"border-radius: 0px;\n"
"border: 0;")
        self.display_webcam_label.setText("")
        self.display_webcam_label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.display_webcam_label.setObjectName("display_webcam_label")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Вот stackoverflow.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * 
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui 
from PyQt5.QtGui import * 
from PyQt5.QtCore import * 
from ui import Ui_Form
import cv2


class Thread1(QThread):
    changePixmap = pyqtSignal(QImage)
    
    def __init__(self, webcam_live, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.webcam_live = webcam_live

    def run(self):
        cap1 = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
        ret1, image1 = cap1.read()

        try:
            im1 = cv2.cvtColor(image1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        except Exception as e:
            self.exit_thr_and_error.emit()

        self.webcam_live.height1, self.webcam_live.width1, channel1 = im1.shape

        cap1.set(3,480)
        cap1.set(4,640)
        cap1.set(5,30)

        while True:
            ret1, image1 = cap1.read()

            if ret1:
                im1 = cv2.cvtColor(image1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                self.webcam_live.height1, self.webcam_live.width1, channel1 = im1.shape
                step1 = channel1 * self.webcam_live.width1
                qImg1 = QImage(im1.data, self.webcam_live.width1, self.webcam_live.height1, step1, QImage.Format_RGB888)

                self.changePixmap.emit(qImg1) 


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form): 
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.dragPos = QtCore.QPoint()

        self.move(0, 0)

        self.height1 = 0
        self.width1 = 0

        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

        self.th1 = Thread1(webcam_live=self)
        self.th1.changePixmap.connect(self.setImage)
        self.th1.start()

    # Widget move event     
        def mouseMove(event):
            if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
                self.move(self.pos() + event.globalPos() - self.dragPos)
                self.dragPos = event.globalPos()
                event.accept()

        self.mouseMoveEvent = mouseMove

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.dragPos = event.globalPos()
    #

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QImage)
    def setImage(self, qImg1):
        pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(qImg1)
        self.display_webcam_label.setPixmap(pixmap.scaled(250, 250, Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding)) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import * 
import cv2

#from ui import Ui_Form
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(250, 250)                                                   # +++
        self.display_webcam_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
#        self.display_webcam_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 231, 221))    # +++
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.display_webcam_label.setFont(font)

#        self.display_webcam_label.setStyleSheet("background: #f11;\n"
#                                                                  transparent   # +++
        self.display_webcam_label.setStyleSheet("background-color: transparent;\n"
"color: #fff;\n"
"border-radius: 0px;\n"
"border: 0;")
        self.display_webcam_label.setText("")
        self.display_webcam_label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.display_webcam_label.setObjectName("display_webcam_label")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))


class Thread1(QThread):
    changePixmap = pyqtSignal(QImage)
    
    def __init__(self, webcam_live, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.webcam_live = webcam_live

    def run(self):
        cap1 = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
        ret1, image1 = cap1.read()

        try:
            im1 = cv2.cvtColor(image1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        except Exception as e:
            self.exit_thr_and_error.emit()

        self.webcam_live.height1, self.webcam_live.width1, channel1 = im1.shape

        cap1.set(3,480)
        cap1.set(4,640)
        cap1.set(5,30)

        while True:
            ret1, image1 = cap1.read()
            if ret1:
                im1 = cv2.cvtColor(image1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                self.webcam_live.height1, self.webcam_live.width1, channel1 = im1.shape
                step1 = channel1 * self.webcam_live.width1
                qImg1 = QImage(im1.data, self.webcam_live.width1, self.webcam_live.height1, step1, QImage.Format_RGB888)
                self.changePixmap.emit(qImg1) 


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form): 
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)                                   # +++
        layout.addWidget(self.display_webcam_label)                  # +++

        self.dragPos = QtCore.QPoint()
        self.move(0, 0)
        self.height1 = 0
        self.width1 = 0

        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

        self.th1 = Thread1(webcam_live=self)
        self.th1.changePixmap.connect(self.setImage)
        self.th1.start()
# +++        
        self.radius = 125                                                  # +++

        # Widget move event     
        def mouseMove(event):
            if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
                self.move(self.pos() + event.globalPos() - self.dragPos)
                self.dragPos = event.globalPos()
                event.accept()
        self.mouseMoveEvent = mouseMove

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.dragPos = event.globalPos()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QImage)
    def setImage(self, qImg1):
        pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(qImg1)
        
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        pixmap = pixmap.scaled(250, 250)                                    # !!!

        rounded = QtGui.QPixmap(pixmap.size())
        rounded.fill(QtGui.QColor("transparent"))        
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(rounded)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
        painter.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(pixmap))
        painter.setPen(QtCore.Qt.NoPen)
        painter.drawRoundedRect(pixmap.rect(), self.radius, self.radius)
        painter.end()                                       
        self.display_webcam_label.setPixmap(rounded)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^            
        
#        self.display_webcam_label.setPixmap(
#            pixmap.scaled(250, 250, Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding)) 
        
                
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, похоже это и правда, то что я пытался добиться,  но я заметил, что мое изображение стало "Сплющенным". Может вы знаете, как сделать так, чтобы мое изображение входило в ровный круг, и сохраняло свое соотношение?